# Is Redis cache effective for simple windows application(management software)?

Tags: wpf, windows, redis, redis-cache

I want to implement caching on a simple desktop application. And I am using `WPF` .NET Framework. So, is `Redis` cache could be effective considering the portability? Or is there any best option available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a cache for a **simple solution**, I suggest you use the **InMemory cache**. But if you are making a **complex solution** you should definitely consider a **Distributed Cache** (e.g. Distributed Redis Cache
), and the reason is that Distributed Cache is:

1. Is coherent (consistent) across requests to multiple servers.
2. Survives server restarts and app deployments. And that's because your cache is
   usually in a different location (e.g. Azure)
3. Doesn't use local memory.
4. Is scalable

---

For more details for InMemory cache [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

For more details for Distributed cache [read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest using `Redis` cache for the WPF desktop app. Why? it makes your application depends on a third-party app. it seems in `.Net` there is a solution for caching in-memory and persisting on a file. You can find more about it on this [LINK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-caching-application-data-in-a-wpf-application?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

Memurai could be an option. It is a native Windows port of Redis.